# Send image to Wordpress API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to send an image (via URL) to Wordpress server via API. With postman, everything is correct and the image is sent, but when doing it with JavaScript, it gives me an error.

What I do is take the URL, I do a fetch and I put the result in a blob that in turn is in a `formData`, but when I send it I always receive an error, either cors if I put: "'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'" (being added to the server) or in the case of removing them it tells me that I cannot send these types of files.

```
const uploadImage = async (originalPost) => {
    const mediaID = originalPost.featured_media;
    const media = await getPetition(`${D_P_C_DOMAIN_ORIGIN}/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${mediaID}`, 'GET');
    const mediaUrl = media.source_url;
    const file = await fetch(mediaUrl, { method: 'GET'});
    if (file.ok) {
        const blob = await file.blob();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blob);
        const TOKEN = btoa(`${D_P_C_USERNAME_DESTINATION}:${D_P_C_PASSWORD_DESTINATION}`);
        await fetch(`${D_P_C_DOMAIN_DESTINATION}/wp-json/wp/v2/media/`, {
            headers: {
               'Authorization': `Basic ${TOKEN}`,
               'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
           
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(responseMedia => {
            console.log(responseMedia);
        })
    }  
};
```

I have put headers, I have removed them, but I cannot upload the image

Comment: `it tells me that I cannot send these types of files`...what does that mean exactly? What error do you get, and where from? P.S. you don't need to set the content-type header, the browser should figure it out and add it for you automatically.

Comment: @ADyson That is exactly the error message that the console returns to me. Thank you very much for the contribution!

Comment: You see that in the browser Console? What is the source of the error? Is it javascript somewhere? Or returned from the php?

Comment: On the other hand, seeing the type of the file is jpg, so it has to be forming well

Comment: @ADyson The source of the error is the wordpress API, which sends me said error in the messages.

Comment: Ok. Well if it doesn't accept the type of file you are uploading, then maybe either test with a different file type, or amend the settings / code in the API (which we cannot see the code or configuration of here). Also, is `cannot send these types of files` really the **exact** error message? And...you said your request worked in Postman, but you haven't given us any details of the Postman request so that we could compare it to what you've written in your JavaScript, and ensure they are equivalent.

Comment: So, you are fetching an image _from_ the WP media library, on the client side, only to send it back _to_ the WP media library ...? Whatever you actually need to achieve here - there must be a better way of doing that, than to send an image onto a round-trip via the client ...?